Could Humans Evolve to Drink Saltwater?
There is an inland sea that is the only source of water (other than rare rainfalls) in one part of the continent in my world. I would like to know whether or not human anatomy is already too derived to adapt to processing the salt in seawater within a period of thousands (rather than millions) of years.

How long do you have?
considering only fully marine animals have evlolved to do what you want

Short period of time - say, less than 10 million years? What technological alternatives are available? (including genetic tech)

@John Whales took around 10 million years to adapt  completely to a fully aquatic life .. howsoever, Sea Otters are not even as 'fully' adapted to an aquatic life as seals are and though most of their water needs are met by their food they also drink seawater, so somewhat less than 10 million years are probably needed .. and the answer to the core question is obviously yes, depending on how soon you want it.

It sort of looks like sea otters did it somewhere in a period between 5 and 2 million years ago? a span of 3 million years, so what do you call a "relatively short period of time" then? if you want to call it 2 million years you're good, 1 million and you're probably still good.

there is no such thing as an inland sea without rain, evaporation is non-stop. If the lake exists then there is several rivers feeding it humans can get fresh water from.

Does this answer your question? Is it biologically plausible for a land animal to drink saltwater and not drink freshwater? (Even if you don't have the freshwater requirement the older question has, yours is but a subset of that one.) Also, insofar as humanity understands evolution (which is precious little), given enough time and opportunity, anything can evolve.

I would not be surprised if marine mammals met their freshwater requirements by eating fish rather than by filtering seawater. And not surprised either if all fish, freshwater and marine alike, had about the same natremia requirements.

@FrançoisJurain they mostly do get 'most' of their water requirements from their food yes, but not all of it all of the time and even Sea Otters (the arguably least fully adapted sea mammal) are able to drink sea water without ill effect.

I can't say for sure, but I think I read someone doing a test where they drank seawater for a long time without dying. The trick was that most people drink it after a long time after desperation and lack of hydration, while this person did it in small quantities but consistent. This way they could keep it down, didn't get sick and could presumably get more hydrated. Probably not recommended for health though. If this is true, it seems a small step for evolution to being able to drink it casually instead of a last resort.

@JBH That question is not relevant to my question because I am asking about humans and whether they could adapt quickly to a challenging environment.

@Jayleth Humans ARE animals and you don't define the phrase "relatively short period of time." Adaptation takes hundreds to thousands of years. Evolution takes millions. If a "relatively short period of time" is a couple of decades then the answer is, "they can't." If you sincerely believe yours isn't a fundamental duplicate of that other question, then it's missing critical details that would get it closed just as quickly.

@JBH Of course I know that humans are animals, but what I meant by saying that I'm asking about humans specifically is that I want to know whether human biology is capable of adapting to this specific prompt in a relatively short period of time. For example "are human kidneys already too derived in one direction to adapt to processing the salt in the seawater?". And to clear up what I mean by "a relatively short period of time" I mean thousands of years rather than millions.

@Jayleth Worst case (or best case, depending on your POV) is that if humans are forced to only drink salt water and if you as a worldbuilder are willing to embrace the enormous number of deaths that would result, the answer is yes. Thousands of years is more than enough time to adapt from the perspective of the most tolerant to saline consumption are going to survive (if the starting population is large enough). Consider the peppered moth and history of English coal.

Just to note, the duplicate target doesn't mention camels. They've amazing blood and kidneys. Probably other stuff too. Worth the OP investigating for inspiration.

No, they can't, because they either survive without or go extinct
Humans who live around the inland sea must be able to survive without doing this, or they cannot colonise the area in order to be exposed to the salt water long term, but if they are able to meet their water needs without drinking the salt water then they are not subject to evolutionary pressure that would drive the evolution of the ability to drink salt water.
Instead of evolving the ability to drink salt water, they will develop better technologies to avoid needing to do this. Perhaps they will domesticate appropriate crops with a high water content, or perhaps they will develop condensation traps to collect water, or perhaps they will discover how and where to dig wells that reach subterranean fresh water.

My original idea was for them to evolve super efficient kidney's, but after reading the first half of your answer I decided that they probably would have made the trek into the desert during a wet season and collected rainwater to last them for a while. They could also subsist off of the water in the plants that they forage from around the sea (assuming that plants that grow in seawater contain freshwater which I am unsure of). During this time they could start developing rudimentary technologies for desalinating the seawater. There wouldn't be any need for them to drink saltwater.

More importantly, without rainfall, there won't be the plants needed to support human life. There are almost no humans in the Nanib desert or the Atacama.

Could there not be plants that get their water from the sea that the humans could eat?

See https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/58134/what-do-halophytes-do-with-the-salt for some information on salt tolerant plants.

Many animals adapted for that. In most cases, they need important changes: for example, penguins have specific glands in their eyes for that. They tear salt.
However, if the penguins have the choice, for example in a zoo, they choose always sweet water. While they can drink salt water, it is a last resort for them.
Whales and dolphins have simply an extraordinary huge kidney for that, beside that their blood is above average salty.
Salt water fishes have two mechanism against salt: most fishes has a very fast water cycle, to prevent accumulating salt, and their organs tolerate salt water.
Sharks are exception, their system preserves urea in their blood and uses it to displace salt. This is why shark meat stinks like pee, making hákarl the second most stinking dish of the world.

It may be possible without evolution.
Have a look at the exploits of Alain Bombard. He crossed the Atlantic without provisions to show humans could survive on fish and a small amount of seawater. This is probably not a diet you could survive on long-term, but  presumably your population will be eating other things, and storing fresh water when they can find it.

No. considering only marine animals have evlolved to do what you want a short amount of time is not enough. The pressure would need to strong and long lasting to get what you want. You need a way remove the salt from the body which is a very specialized adaptation esspecially if you want them to be able ot handle fresh water as well.
Nothing that could be called a "short amount of time" will allow this. ou need a few million years at minimum and that is with a very strong selective pressure.

Being aquatic isn't needed, an increasingly restricted access to non-saline water (which would occur naturally to a species that was becoming increasingly more aquatic spending ever longer at sea) is probably all that's really needed and other ways for that to occur can be imagined than becoming a fully aquatic sea going species.

@Pelinore but you are still talking about several million years, longer than the human species has existed.

Oh yes, or at least probably ;) .. evolution 'can' happen pretty fast of course, depending on the specific adaption, a single mutation can provide a significant enough advantage to see it spread throughout a population within a matter of only thousands or even mere hundreds of years, faster even if you have a small isolated population and the founder effect, but without knowing precisely what the adaptions are and how many consecutive mutations are required to get there (something that would need more reading than I'm going to do for this ;D) one has to be a little conservative ;)

In order to evolve a trait each step from the start until it is fully developed needs to increase (or at least not decrease) the fitness of individuals having that trait in order for such a trait to be evolved successfully.
That would mean that the people living near the lake needed to consume unhealthy amounts of salts before they could handle it in order to evolve a higher tolerance to salt.
Another question would be how many generations would be needed to evolve this trait. Humans need a long time before reproducing so evolution affects us slower then many other species. So the people living near this lake would need to be living their for millennia to evolve to drink salt water.
Another question is how the adaptation to drink salt water would affect humans that don't drink salt water. If someone that can drink salt water would live a normal life would they need to eat in order to have enough energy for their larger kidney then the evolution for this trait would have started once people entered this new salt rich environment. If people could have kidneys powerful enough to filter high amounts of salt without having any negative impact on them then the trait could have evolved before it's being needed. The reason why people are advised to always finish their antibiotic treatment is because some bacteria may have higher resistance or persistence to that antibiotic even though it wasn't needed before. This can happen because higher resistance and persistence to an antibiotic doesn't necessarily have any negative effect on them when it's not needed. So some of the people coming to that lake might have already been able to handle high amounts of salt before coming there.
To recap. In order to evolve the trait fast you need to check these boxes.

Is every step in the evolution of this trait advantageous?
How long do humans need to evolve that trait?
Could the evolution of this trait have started before it is needed?

As I don't know to much about how we deal with salt or how the ability to handle high amounts of salt evolved in other species I don't know the answer to those questions. If you want to go in depth on the third question I suggest you read up on river dolphins and how much salt they can handle as they could handle sea water once. If they lost that trait 3 is unlikely otherwise it's possible.
